# Convert PByte to Mat OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, playstation3

I am using PS3 camera with opencv it works with PByte data type.Gives PByte as frame result.In SDK samples they use IplImage.I want use Mat instead IplImage.But i cant convert PByte to Mat.How can i convert PByte to Mat ? Example In SDK

```
     IplImage *pCapImage;
    PBYTE pCapBuffer = NULL;
    cvGetImageRawData(pCapImage, &pCapBuffer);
    while(_running)
        {
            cvGetImageRawData(pCapImage, &pCapBuffer);
            CLEyeCameraGetFrame(_cam, pCapBuffer, (i==0)?2000:0);
}
//Function from SDK

IMPORT(bool) CLEyeCameraGetFrame(CLEyeCameraInstance cam, PBYTE pData, int waitTimeout = 2000);
```

//MyCode //I use 2 camera.

```
    cv::Mat pCapImage[2];
    PBYTE pCapBuffer = NULL;
    while(_running){

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                                  //trying convert
                    pCapImage[i] = cv::Mat (cvSize(w, h), 4, &pCapBuffer,IPL_DEPTH_8U).clone();

                    CLEyeCameraGetFrame(_cam[i], pCapBuffer);
                }

                Mat pCapImageMatL = pCapImage[0];
                Mat pCapImageMatR = pCapImage[1];
                imshow(_windowNameL, pCapImageMatL);
                imshow(_windowNameR, pCapImageMatR);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have successfully converted `PBYTE` to `IplImage *`, you can further convert it to `cv::Mat` as follows:

```
IplImage *pCapImage;  // this is the IplImage * that you have converted from PBYTE 
cv::Mat pCapImageMat(pCapImage);
cvReleaseImage(&pCapImage); // free the previous memory
```

Comment: can i make this without using pCapImage. I just want pCapBuffer to Mat directly.Because in documentation i see IplImage need manuel memory management.

Comment: @user1924375 Then just release previous memory. It's easy. Please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OpenCV 3, IPlImage has been deprecated. So @herohuyongtao answer won't work.

In this case, the workaround is

```
cv::Mat frame;
frame = cv::cvarrToMat(pCapImage);
```

Comment: can i make this without using pCapImage. I just want pCapBuffer to Mat directly.Because in documentation i see IplImage need manuel memory management.